# Selenium AdBlock not working

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, google-chrome-extension, adblock

I am using Selenium webdriver options to add the AdBlock extension using the relevant .crx file as follows:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_extension('AdBlock_v3.24.0.crx')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('Path to chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
```

This adds the extension fine, but does not block any ad's on any of the pages which I visit (works fine when visiting these pages on a normal chrome browser with the same version of AdBlock).

Could anyone please advise on what the problem might be?

Comment: Have you tried adding the full path to the `.crx` file?

Answer (score 0):

The solution you tried although technically sound not always work as intended, so personally I've found another way to do it.
Because many times I need a lot of things that are better done manually, extensions, authentications, certain cookies, etc

I use folders as profiles, I run:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=selenium") 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("www.google.com")
```

Then I manually install the Ad-blocker or any other extensions and do the logins I need now every-time I start the Webdriver with that folder everything is there

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=selenium") 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("www.google.com") #Now you can see the Extensions and the logins done are present
```

The advantage is you can use multiple folders with different setting and Extensions without the need to install and uninstall Ad-blocker, change settings, change logins etc

Answer (score -4):

```
options = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Try using with firefox.
Notify me if it worked or not!!!